# Getting the contents of a text field as a number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a textfield in my app, whre the user can enter any number (I have set to Number pad)
I want to store this as an integer in a variable
I am writing

```
int numOfYears = [numOfYearsFld text];
```

But for some reason it is taking it incorrectly e.g. if user enters 10, it taakes as 10214475

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intValue` returns an `int`.

`integerValue` returns an `NSInteger`.

```
NSInteger numOfYears = [[numOfYearsFld text] integerValue];
```

Comment: int and NSInteger are interchangeable, provided a 32-bit architecture. So it can't be a problem here, if that's what you meant. Well, I agree it's better to be NSInteger though.

Answer (score 1):

[numOfYearsFld text] will be a NSString*. Try:

```
int numOfYears = [[numOfYearsFld text] intValue];
```

Comment: Tried this. Does not fix the problem.

Comment: What value you get when you NSlog(@"%d %@",numOfYears,numOfYearsFld.text); after assigning numOfYears?

Comment: +1 for knowing the difference between an `int` and an `NSInteger` unlike the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int numOfYears = [[numOfYearsFid text] intValue];
```

or, preferably

```
NSInteger numOfYears = [[numOfYearsFid text] integerValue];
```

`intValue` returns an `int` and `integerValue` returns an `NSInteger`.

Comment: Tried this. Does not fix the problem.

Comment: Then your `numOfYearsFid` or `[numOfYearsFid text]` may not be valid. I would check outlet connections between numOfYearsFid and your UITextField.